# Update data-* with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a way to update the value of a `data-*` ([HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)) element of a `div` with `JavaScript` or `jQuery`?

Comment: `$(selector).data('prefix',newValue)` https://api.jquery.com/data/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: @Satpal Not sure it is the question but both methods you provided don't update the attribute value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.prototype.attr` or `jQuery.prototype.data` if your using jQuery

`$(selector).attr('data-something', 'stuff')`

`$(selector).data('something', 'stuff')`

Or you can use `dataset` or `Element.prototype.setAttribute` for vanilla javascript

`document.querySelector(selector).dataset['something'] = 'stuff'`
`document.querySelector(selector).dataset.something = 'stuff'`
`document.querySelector(selector).setAttribute('data-something') = 'stuff'`

Comment: upvote for showing the `vanialla js` and `jQuery` way

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
<div data-xyz="50">

$("div").data("xyz",30)
```